# Deploying to google app engine flexible with go.mod fails because it is looking for dependent libraries in GOPATH

Tags: go, app-engine-flexible, go-modules

I have the helloworld app from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine_flexible/helloworld) with a couple of modifications.

1. I've used logrus (to bring in dependency to an external lib)
2. I've added a go.mod using go mod init
3. I have checkout this code outside of my GOPATH.

Everything works on localhost. I'm able to see the hello message on localhost:8080. When I attempt to do a gcloud app deploy I get the following error:

```
staging for go1.11
Staging Flex app: failed analyzing /home/.../code/app-engine-gomod: cannot find package "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" in any of:
    ($GOROOT not set)
    /home/.../go/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus (from $GOPATH)
GOPATH: /home/.../go
```

I've tried with and without `go mod vendor` doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever work out what was happening here?

Comment: @Oliver, no I didn't. I started using app engine flex with a Dockerfile.

Comment: Ah that's annoying, I went back to using dep. As it's consistent with other parts of the project. I feel like so much of this is half finished and half documented. :(

Comment: Looks like here is the official answer: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34107

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for you - it's not pretty. I don't know why app engine doesn't try to resolve dependencies with go modules and instead looks just in the $GOPATH.

My workaround is to just copy the appropriate folder in go modules cache back to the Go Path. I'd love to know if someone has a better solution.

Your mod cache should be in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`

Copy the dependencies you need, into your `$GOPATH/src` folder and you should be good to go.

Related issue, hope this helps someone. This led me down a rabbit hole because I recently switched to Go modules, and GAE was complaining about a bug in a dependency which was fixed in a newer version of it. I updated the dependency multiple times, it worked fine on local testing but I kept getting the same error on `app deploy`. Eventually I realised what was happening: when running your code locally, Go correctly assembled dependencies from the go modules cache - app engine was taking it from the 'old' location from the Go Path. Once you enable Go modules `go get` only updates the mod cache.

Comment: I have a similar problem, copying did not really help in my case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822057/deploying-to-google-app-engine-flexible-for-go1-12-fails

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of App Engine Standard and Flex, both support the Go 1.11 runtime. Now, we know Go 1.11 [introduced](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Preliminary_module_support) experimental support for Go modules, keeping compatibility with GOPATH. However, while using Go modules through a `go.mod` file is an approach [presented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/specifying-dependencies) for Standard, it is [not mentioned at all](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-go-libraries) for Flex.

So, for Flex, either you have everything under the GOPATH, following the indications in the docs, or stick with the workaround provided by @shrumm.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this and have better control on the runtime and its dependencies, I found that using a `custom` runtime with a provided Dockerfile works best. Have a look at this [github project](https://github.com/emicklei/kiya-webapp) for an example setup.