# Deploying to Google App engine flexible for go1.12 fails

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a service that looks somewhat like this -

```
service
  |
  |__cmd
  |  |_main.go
  |
  |_ app.yaml
  |_ cloudbuild.yaml
  |_ service.go
  |_ someHelper.go
```

I have a few private packages that I include in go.mod and after a lengthy build process I have an image that can be deployed to GAE. However, I get this error after I deploy -

```
Starting Step #6 - "deploy app"
Step #6 - "deploy app": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #6 - "deploy app": ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Staging command [/builder/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/go-app-stager /workspace/app.yaml /workspace /tmp/tmpuwereWq0/tmpdfWB0wiJ] failed with return code [1].
Step #6 - "deploy app":
Step #6 - "deploy app": ------------------------------------ STDOUT ------------------------------------
Step #6 - "deploy app": ------------------------------------ STDERR ------------------------------------
Step #6 - "deploy app": 2019/09/06 12:17:42 staging for go1.12
Step #6 - "deploy app": 2019/09/06 12:17:42 Staging Flex app: failed analyzing /workspace: the root of your app needs to be package "main" (currently "some_service_name")
Step #6 - "deploy app": GOPATH: /go
Step #6 - "deploy app": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #6 - "deploy app":
Finished Step #6 - "deploy app"
```

My cloud build sample file is posted here - https://gist.github.com/automaticalldramatic/961dbd2a92a6b9518835688eb2df2d67

Any help or insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: what about the error message? `the root of your app needs to be package "main" (currently "some_service_name")`

Comment: that's what I want help with. So, I figured this could be a problem - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/198#issuecomment-359106287 Also, I have changed the app structure to reflect what GAE docs recommend.

Comment: The main file directive `main: ./cmd/service` does not seem too work with app engine. I am closing this issue as this app structure is not supported by GAE I feel

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuration-files does not really support this

Comment: You need your `app.yaml` in the same folder as your `main` package (in your case `cmd` I assume), not in the `service` folder where clearly your `some_service_name` package resides.

Comment: yeah, I made that change .... thanks for helping though .... I have other problems now, the app deployment step fails while deploying, works fine when staging the app - looking into it

Comment: I recommend you to prefer a Dockerfile if you use appengine flex. Then deploy your container. By the way, you can get portability, to other platform (GKE, Cloud Run) and even multi cloud portability container.