# Not able to deploy a Go app to GAE because a local package is not found

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I have a simple Go app with the following folder structure

```
-myapp
  -src
    -main
      main.go
      main.yaml
    -mypackage
      mypackage.go
    go.mod
```

`main` references `mypackage`. The **go.mod** file is simply

```
module github.com/myname/myapp

go 1.14
```

I can build the app with `go build -o mymain -v ./src/main` and everything works.

The issue is when I try to deploy this to Google Application Engine.
To deploy I run these commands

```
export GOPATH=/Users/blah/blah/myapp
gcloud app deploy server.yaml
```

and I got this error

```
Staging Flex app: failed analyzing /Users/blah/blah/myapp/src/main: cannot find package "github.com/myname/myapp/src/mypackage" in any of:
    ($GOROOT not set)
    /Users/blah/blah/myapp/src/github.com/myname/myapp/src/mypackage (from $GOPATH)
GOPATH: /Users/blah/blah/myapp
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using go.mod in an App Engine Flex deployment. Unfortunately, the Flex Go runtime does not support Go modules currently.

To work around the limitation, you can:

- Deploy with App Engine Standard, which supports use of Go modules. ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/specifying-dependencies))
- Copy the appropriate folder in Go modules cache back to the Go Path. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757526/11957811.
- "+1" and follow the Google Public Issue Tracker for the feature request for Flex to support Go modules. See https://issuetracker.google.com/147579198.